# Model verb with multiple objects sentence structure

Tags: sentence-structure, modal-verb

I want to translate the English sentence:

> You must drink water outside the room.

Where would one place the object *water* in the modal verb sentence structure? What would be the rule for placing multiple objects?

> Du musst Wasser außerhalb des Zimmers trinken.
>   Du musst außerhalb des Zimmers Wasser trinken.

Comment: There are no multiple objects in your example sentence; only one. I don’t get what you’re trying to ask. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: Statt außen muss es außerhalb heißen, statt das Zimmer des Zimmers, sonst sind beide Formen richtig, aber Sätze erfordern in beiden Sprachen Satzzeichen.

Comment: I will try to give you a helpful comment. To me it's rather obvious that you confused the clause parts "object" and "adverbial". Here "water" is an object, but "ausserhalb des Zimmers" is an adverbial. Change this by editing your post, and it will look OK. As a side note if you really mean "must" in English, I wouldn't translate that with a simple "müssen"", sondern "unbedingt müssen". Maybe you wanted to say "have to drink water"?

Answer (score 1):

You should use *außerhalb* (outside of) together with "des Zimmers" (Genitiv). So the sentences become:

> 1. Du musst Wasser außerhalb des Zimmers trinken.
> 2. Du musst außerhalb des Zimmers Wasser trinken.

Grammatically both sentences are correct. However the order determines the meaning. In the first sentence, the meaning is: If you want to drink water you have to do it outside the room. (This is probably the meaning you want.) In the second sentence, it sounds to me more like: Whether you want it or not, you have to go outside and drink water there.

The construction with *außerhalb des Zimmers* sounds slightly non-native to me. Probably a German would rather say something like:

> Sie können/dürfen hier nicht trinken.
>   Sie müssen draußen trinken.

Comment: The second one can also mean: If your are outside f the room, you have to drink water.

Comment: @CarstenS  yes, depending on what word is beeing stressed